# Сборка webpack ES6 не работает в IE

Tags: internet-explorer, webpack, babel

Добрый день. Бьюсь над проблемой  - не работает сайт (JS-код) во всех версиях IE. Хотя бы edge - и тот не хочет...

devtools в IE edge указывает на эту строку:

```js
eval("/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function($) {Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, \"__esModule\", { value: true });\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__sass_main_scss__ = __webpack_require__(448);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__sass_main_scss___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__sass_main_scss__);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__sass_swiper_css__ = __webpack_require__(475);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__sass_swiper_css___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__sass_swiper_css__);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__index_scss__ = __webpack_require__(473);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__index_scss___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__index_scss__);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_normalize_css__ = __webpack_require__(165);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_normalize_css___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_normalize_css__);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_core_js__ = __webpack_require__(169);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_core_js___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_core_js__);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_ymaps__ = __webpack_require__(477);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_ymaps___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_ymaps__);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_swiper__ = __webpack_require__(476);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__components_aside_aside__ = __webpack_require__(456);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__components_modal_modal__ = __webpack_require__(457);\n/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__animate_js__ = __webpack_require__(478);\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n // http://idangero.us/swiper/api/\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n// Slider\r\n\r\nvar swiper = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_swiper__[\"a\" /* default */]('.swiper-container', {\r\n    speed: 500,\r\n    pagination: {\r\n        el: '.swiper-pagination',\r\n        clickable: true,\r\n    },\r\n    autoplay: {\r\n        delay: 5000,\r\n    },\r\n});\r\n\r\n// Высота секций в размер экрана\r\n\r\nconst setSectionHeight = () => {\r\n    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1200) {\r\n        let wheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;\r\n        const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');\r\n        [].map.call(sections, function(elem) {\r\n            elem.style.height = wheight + 'px';\r\n        });\r\n        return sections;\r\n    }\r\n};\r\n\r\n// Правки для Firefox\r\n\r\nconst get_name_browser = () => {  \r\n    const ua = navigator.userAgent;\r\n    if (ua.search(/Edge/) > 0) return 'Edge';\r\n    if (ua.search(/Chrome/) > 0) return 'Google Chrome';\r\n    if (ua.search(/Firefox/) > 0) return 'Firefox';\r\n    if (ua.search(/Opera/) > 0) return 'Opera';\r\n    if (ua.search(/Safari/) > 0) return 'Safari';\r\n    if (ua.search(/MSIE/) > 0) return 'Internet Explorer';\r\n    if (ua.search(/Trident/) > 0) return 'Trident';\r\n    return 'Не определен';\r\n};\r\n\r\nif (get_name_browser() == 'Firefox') {\r\n    const sliderImage = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-slide');\r\n    [].forEach.call(sliderImage, image => {\r\n        image.children[0].style.width = 'unset';\r\n    });    \r\n}\r\n\r\n// Карта\r\n\r\n__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_ymaps___default.a.load().then(maps => {\r\n    const map = new maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {\r\n        center: [60.699, 28.752],\r\n        zoom: 14,\r\n    });\r\n    map.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');\r\n    const Placemark = new maps.Placemark([60.699, 28.752], { \r\n        hintContent: 'Вереск!', \r\n        balloonContent: '', \r\n    });\r\n\r\n    map.geoObjects.add(Placemark);\r\n}).catch(error => console.log('Failed to load Yandex Maps', error));  \r\n\r\n// Анимации\r\n\r\nconst anim = new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__animate_js__[\"a\" /* default */];\r\n\r\n$(window).ready(function() {\r\n    setSectionHeight();\r\n    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1200) {\r\n        anim.description();\r\n        anim.play();\r\n    }\r\n});\r\n\r\n$(window).scroll(function () {\r\n    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1200) {\r\n        anim.play();\r\n    }\r\n});\r\n\r\n$(window).resize(function () {\r\n    setSectionHeight();\r\n});\r\n\n/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(__webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__(83)))\n\n//////////////////\n// WEBPACK FOOTER\n// ./source/pages/index/index.js\n// module id = 459\n// module chunks = 0\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./source/pages/index/index.js?");
```

В хроме / фарфоксе все отлично.
Для IE пришлось поковыряться в различных ISSUE  - но ничего не срабатывает.
Догадываюсь, что дело в babel.

Зависимости следующие касательно babel:

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-ie": "^6.7.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
```

Что я сделал:

1. Прикрепил babel-polyfill - не спасло. Установил babel-preset-env и
   (код ниже) прописал `'browsers':['last 5 versions', 'ie >= 9']`
2. Скачал `es2015-ie` пресет  - не спасло.
3. Почитал что UglifyJS может все вредить - отключено (код ниже).
4. Почитал здесь на форумах, что может спасти  плагин core-js. Установил и как  было предложено - импортировал в код  `import 'core-js'` - не помогло...
5. Попробовал с плагином core-js-webpack-plugin - не сработало.

```js
        return merge([
            common,
            extractCSS(),
            js(),            
            // uglifyJS(),
        ]);
```

Конфигурация webpack - по данной ссылке -https://github.com/davegahn/VERESK/blob/master/webpack.config.js.

Итоговая конфигурация babel.js - выкладываю код:

```js
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
     presets: [
                      'babel-polyfill',  
                      'es2015',
                      ['env', {
                        'targets': {
                            'browsers':['last 5 versions', 'ie >= 9']                            
                        }
                      }],
                      'es2015-ie',
                      'stage-3'
                    ]
    }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Также весь JS не работает в android browser. Думаю, что причина в этом же.

Comment: Удалось в итоге победить ие?

Comment: Подтверждаю аналогичную проблему! Ищу решение.